# Javascript access class methods outside of class?

Tags: javascript

See my example below:

```
(function() {
  // Initialize the socket & handlers
  var connectToServer = function() {
    var warbleSocket = new SockJS('http://url.com:5555/warble');

    warbleSocket.onopen = function() {
      clearInterval(connectRetry);
      $('.connect-status')
        .removeClass('disconnected')
        .addClass('connected')
        .text('Connected');
    };

    warbleSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
      $('#warble-msg').text(e.data);
    };

    warbleSocket.onclose = function() {
      clearInterval(connectRetry);
      connectRetry = setInterval(connectToServer, 1000);
      $('.connect-status')
        .removeClass('connected')
        .addClass('disconnected')
        .text('Disconnected');
    };

    // Connect the text field to the socket
    $('.msg-sender').off('input').on('input', function() {
      warbleSocket.send($('.msg-sender input').val()); 
    });
  };
  var connectRetry = setInterval(connectToServer, 1000);



  connectRetry.warbleSocket.send("Hi there");  

})();
```

What i would like is to be able to access `warbleSocket.send` from outside of `connectRetry`

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

to expose API from IIFE in JS:

```
...
    return {
        send: warbleSocket.send
    }
})();
```

http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Couldent get this to work i get `connectToServer.send is not a function`

Comment: It kind of works, but it breaks this line when trying to reconnect: `connectRetry = setInterval(connectToServer, 1000);` am getting this error: `SyntaxError: missing ] after element list`